# php - Problemas al insertar datos MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Buenas, estoy intentando insertar datos desde mi formulario, pero cuando presiono el botón submit me arroja el mensaje de:

**"Conexión hecha"**

Que es el mensaje de mi archivo php de **conexion**, nada más. El código para insertar lo tengo en otro archivo. 
Esto es mi código.

El de mi formulario **venta_cliente.php**:

```
<div class="container clear_both padding_fix">
        <!--\\\\\\\ container  start \\\\\\-->



        <form action="php/registrar_cliente.php" method="POST">

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="idnom">Nombre:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idnom" name="nnombre" REQUIRED placeholder="Ingresar Nombre">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="idape">Apellidos:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idape" name="napellido" REQUIRED placeholder="Ingresar Apellidos">
                </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="idtdoc">Tipo de Documento:</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="idtdoc" name="ntdoc">
                  <option value="DNI">DNI</option>
                  <option value="RUC">RUC</option>
                </select>
              </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="iddoc">Documento:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iddoc" name="ndoc" REQUIRED placeholder="Numero de Documento">
                </div>


              <div class="row">

                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                  <label for="iddir">Direccion:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iddir" name="ndireccion" REQUIRED placeholder="Ingresar Direccion">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
                  <label for="idtelf">Telf/Movil:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idtelf" name="ntelf" REQUIRED placeholder="Ingresar Telf o Movil">
                </div>

              </div>


                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Registrar"></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</button>

        </form>


      </div>
      <!--\\\\\\\ container  end \\\\\\-->
```

Y este es el código de mi archivo para registrar **registrar_cliente.php**:

```
<?php 
include'conexion.php';

$nombre=$_POST['nnombre'];
$apellido=$_POST['napellido'];  
$tipo_doc=$_POST['ntdoc'];
$documento=$_POST['ndoc'];
$direccion=$_POST['ndireccion'];
$telf=$_POST['ntelf'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$sql = "INSERT INTO cliente (nombre, apellidos, tipo_doc, dni, direccion, telfmovil)
VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$tipo_doc', '$documento', '$direccion', '$telf')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Datos registrados correctamente";
} else {
    echo "Ups! Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

}

$conn->close();

 ?>
```

Y el código de mi archivo **conexion.php**:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123";
$dbname = "dbagricola";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die("Conexion a la Base de Dato fallida:  " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Conexion hecha";


?>
```

Los archivos **registrar_cliente.php** y **conexion.php** están alojados en una carpeta llamada PHP, ¿eso afecta para insertar los datos?

Si saben cual es mi error estaría muy agradecido en que me lo hagan ver para corregirlo.

Comment: Te comento lo mismo que te dije en otra pregunta que hiciste: ese código es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL, deberías utilizar sentencias preparadas en lugar de generar las sentencias dinámicamente.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El problema que veo es:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//Esta variable no existe
```

para que funcione con lo que tienes, deberias añadir lo siguiente al formulario:

```
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Registrar">
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias, soy nuevo en PHP y no sabia que se agrega el atributo nombre(name) para el input. Pensaba que lo del 'submit' era por lo del "type".

Answer (score 5):

Te voy a contestar a tu recompensa adicional, ya que la respuesta que esta aceptada está claro y correcto, el código `PHP` la he avanzado un poco, que es la parte que veo demasiado vulnerable, un caso del código actual, no veo lógico obtener directamente los datos desde el formulario sin ninguna comprobación en `PHP`.

En este caso podríamos hacer antes una comprobación si está definida nuestro formulario y comprobaría que ningún campo (input) este vacío, y en caso contrario obtendría los datos.

Para obtener los datos, utilizaría `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, cuando uno utiliza sentencias `mysqli`, en caso de usar sentencias `prepare()` no sería correcto usar dicha función.

`mysqli_real_escape_string` — Escapa los caracteres especiales de una cadena para usarla en una sentencia SQL, tomando en cuenta el conjunto de caracteres actual de la conexión

**Ejemplo**:

```
$nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nnombre']);
```

> **Nota:** podríamos hacer más comprobaciones si uno desea implementar más seguridad, como contar el mínimo y el máximo en caracteres de una cadena obtenido desde el formulario o algún `expresión regular PHP` para validar el documentos DNI, etc.

Como te han mencionado, es mejor crear `sentencias preparadas` para proteger mejor nuestras sentencias contra ataques de `inyección SQL`

Los ataques de `inyección SQL` solo puede ocurrir si no formateamos las partes de nuestra consulta de manera invulnerable.

Un formato malicioso seria:

```
SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre='Foo';
```

Un formato correcto seria:

```
SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre='Foo\';
```

Fuente (Ingles):

- https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection

Fuente SOes:

- [Es posible protegerme contra una inyeccion sql si lo paso por get?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36119/es-posible-protegerme-contra-una-inyeccion-sql-si-lo-paso-por-get/36149#36149)

### Ejemplo **sentencias preparadas**:

Código HTML:

> **Nota:** el atributo `name` es nuestro identificador, para obtener nuestros datos segun caso por metodo `POST` o `GET`, en nuestro caso va ser por metodo `POST`.

```
<form action="php/registrar_cliente.php" method="POST">

   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="idnom">Nombre:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idnom" name="nnombre" REQUIRED placeholder="Ingresar Nombre">
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="idape">Apellidos:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idape" name="napellido" REQUIRED placeholder="Ingresar Apellidos">
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="idtdoc">Tipo de Documento:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="idtdoc" name="ntdoc">
         <option value="DNI">DNI</option>
         <option value="RUC">RUC</option>
      </select>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="iddoc">Documento:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iddoc" name="ndoc" REQUIRED placeholder="Numero de Documento">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <label for="iddir">Direccion:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="iddir" name="ndireccion" REQUIRED placeholder="Ingresar Direccion">
         </div>

         <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
            <label for="idtelf">Telf/Movil:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idtelf" name="ntelf" REQUIRED placeholder="Ingresar Telf o Movil">
          </div>

     </div>    
     
     <input type="submit" name="registrar" class="btn btn-primary" value="Registrar">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</button>

</form>
```

Código PHP (php/registrar_cliente.php)

```
<?php

//Reseteo variables.
$msg = $nombre = $apellido = $tipo_doc = $documento = $direccion = $telf = NULL;

//Comprobación definición formulario, mediante el identificador input submit.    
if(isset($_POST['registrar'])){

    //Comprobamos que no haya ningun campo vacio del formulario.
    if (empty($_POST['nnombre']) || empty($_POST['napellido']) || empty($_POST['ndoc']) || empty($_POST['ndireccion']) || empty($_POST['ntelf'])) {
        //Mensaje Error.
        $msg = "Ups, todos los campos del formulario son obligatorios.";
    } else {
        //Verdadero, obtenemos datos.
        $nombre = $_POST['nnombre'] ?: '';
        $apellido = $_POST['napellido'] ?: '';  
        $tipo_doc = $_POST['ntdoc'] ?: '';
        $documento = $_POST['ndoc'] ?: '';
        $direccion = $_POST['ndireccion'] ?: '';
        $telf = $_POST['ntelf'] ?: '';
    }

    //Comprobamos que todos nuestros datos sean verdadero.
    if ($nombre && $apellido && $tipo_doc && $documento && $direccion && $telf) {

        //Requeremos conexión MySQL (¡Importante! Llamamos a nuestra conexión donde vamos a utilizarlo).
        require_once'conexion.php';
        
        //Sentencia preparada.
        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cliente (nombre,apellidos,tipo_doc,dni,direccion,telfmovil) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");      

        //Ligamos parametros marcadores (?,?,?,... es decir, $nombre,$apellido,$tipo_doc,...)
    
        //Especificación del tipo de caracteres:

        //i     la variable correspondiente es de tipo entero
        //d     la variable correspondiente es de tipo double
        //s     la variable correspondiente es de tipo string
        //b     la variable correspondiente es un blob y se envía en paquetes
        
        $sql->bind_param("ssssss",$nombre,$apellido,$tipo_doc,$documento,$direccion,$telf); 

        //Ejecutar sentencia
        $ejecutar = $sql->execute();
        
        //Comprobamos que se ejecutó correctamente.
        if (false===$ejecutar) { #Falso

            exit('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($sql->error));

        } else { #Verdadero.

            //Mensaje OK.
            $msg = ucfirst($nombre) . " tus datos se registraron con exito.";
        }

        //Cerrar sentencia.
        $sql->close();      

    }

}//Fin isset.

//Mensajes OK / ERRORES.
echo $msg;        

?>
```